# Why $\mathcal{F}_{t_i}\subset \mathcal{F}_{t_j}$ if $i<j$?

Tags: probability, measure-theory, stochastic-calculus

I read an answer from this question: [$E[e_te_s\Delta B_t\Delta B_s]$ for $\Delta B_t$ Brownian motion increments and $e_t(\omega)$ a measurable function.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/990219/ee-te-s-delta-b-t-delta-b-s-for-delta-b-t-brownian-motion-increments-and/990231#990231)

I don't quite understand the meaning of $\mathcal{F}$-measurable, even though I have read its definition and this answer: [What does it mean by $\mathcal{F}$-measurable?](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/508801/254943)

Is there any intuitive explanation on what is $\mathcal{F}$-measurable, and why it is obvious that $\mathcal{F}_{t_i}\subset \mathcal{F}_{t_j}$ if $i<j$? How to decide whether a random variable is $\mathcal{F}$-measurable or not?